# BaseAdapter is not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner in android app development. Please help me resolve this problem.

I have an MainActivityFragment on which I have to fetch from a remote location and  populate some image data. To do that I've used AsyncTask in a separate class and called it from the MainActivityFragment class. I also created another class called ImageAdapter that extends BaseAdapter.

When I ran the app by putting some drawable images in an array. The code worked pretty well. But when I Fetched the JSON data from AsyncTask and extracted the image path from the JSON and assigned that 'extracted image path value' to a field in ImageAdapter class from the AsyncTask class, the app ran smoothly but no images are populated on the screen. I tried putting some debug points in ImageAdapter class and in other places but couldn't find the problem, as the app never reached the debug point, when the app was ran on Debug mode.

MainActivityFragment.java

```
   package com.example.pavan.moviesapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

// API : f9b69f2b96bfaa9b1748f12afbe14cea
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

//    JSONObject jsonObject;
//    JSONObject objectsInJSONArray;
//    ArrayAdapter<String> moviePoster;


    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

//        new ImageAdater.FetchMovieData().execute("POPULARITY.desc");



        final GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_grid_view);


        new FetchMovieData().execute("POPULARITY.desc");

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdater(getContext()));

//        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdater());



        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"position : " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

FetchMovieData.java

```
package com.example.pavan.moviesapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by pavan on 3/7/2016.
 */

public class FetchMovieData extends AsyncTask {

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONObject objectsInJSONArray;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        if (params.length == 0)
            return null;

        String API_KEY = "f9b69f2b96bfaa9b1748f12afbe14cea";
//        String IMAGE_SIZE = "w185";
        String BASE_URL = " http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
        // String SORT_BY = "POPULARITY.desc";
        String SORT_BY = (String) params[0];

        String SORT_BY_PARAM = "sort_by";
        String API_KEY_PARAM = "api_key";
        Uri.Builder uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(SORT_BY_PARAM, SORT_BY)
                .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY_PARAM, API_KEY);

        uri.build();


        String MoviesJSONdata = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

            //Creating a request to the moviedb api
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Reading the input stream
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            if (inputStream == null){
                //do nothing
                Log.e("input stream is null ", inputStream.toString());
                return null;}

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            if (stringBuffer.length() == 0)
                return null;

            MoviesJSONdata = stringBuffer.toString();



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return MoviesJSONdata;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        try {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            ImageAdater imageAdater = new ImageAdater();



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                objectsInJSONArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < objectsInJSONArray.length(); j++) {
               imageAdater.moviePoster.add(objectsInJSONArray.getString("poster_path"));
//                    System.out.println("string list content: " + imageAdater.moviePoster.get(j));
                }
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.pavan.moviesapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by pavan on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class ImageAdater extends BaseAdapter {



   public ArrayList<String> moviePoster = new ArrayList();
    Context context;
    ImageView movie_posters_imageView;
//    View movie_posters_imageView;
    String BASE_POSTER_URL;

//    int[] imageId = {
//            R.drawable.one,
//            R.drawable.two,
//            R.drawable.three,
//            R.drawable.four,
//            R.drawable.five,
//            R.drawable.six
//    };


    public ImageAdater(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public ImageAdater() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//        return imageId.length;
        return moviePoster.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
//        return imageId[position];
        return moviePoster.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.movie_image, parent, false);
            movie_posters_imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster_image_view);
        }

        else
            movie_posters_imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

//        movie_posters_imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//        movie_posters_imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        movie_posters_imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        BASE_POSTER_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";


            System.out.println("movie poster : " + moviePoster.get(position));

            System.out.println("poster url : " + BASE_POSTER_URL+moviePoster.get(position));

//        Picasso.with(context).load(imageId[position]).centerCrop().resize(185*2,278*2).into(movie_posters_imageView);

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(BASE_POSTER_URL + moviePoster.get(position))
                    .noFade()
                    .resize(185 * 2, 278 * 2)
                    .into(movie_posters_imageView);

        return movie_posters_imageView;
    }


}
```

movie_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/movie_poster_image_view">

</ImageView>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context="com.example.pavan.moviesapp.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/movie_grid_view"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `moviePoster` is always empty. getCount is returning its size, ergo 0

Comment: @Blackbelt thank you for your help :)